# How to pass raw body parameters in post api

Tags: php, json, laravel, api

I am using Delhivery API, I hit it in postman, its working there.
This is post method api, i am passing my values in raw.
The format for passing data is in below screenshot
[This is the format to pass variable in post method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu6qF.png)

[This i passed in postman and its working here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r4bb.png)

Please tell me how to pass these data in the same format in laravel PHP post method. and pass authentication header.

Comment: You can pass authentication in header in Bearer token

Comment: i am doing like this
https://snipboard.io/qUop50.jpg

Comment: check this screenshot

Comment: you Guzzle it's built-in laravell http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use **PHP CURL extension**

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://staging-express.delhivery.com/api/cmu/create.json",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "Body goes here",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    'x-api-key: XXXXXX',
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: Q.4- Getting error "format key missing in the post" in Package Order Creation API response?
Ans- "format=json&data=" (without quotes) is mandatory to pass in the request payload in order creation in our system.
I am getting this error tell me how to pass data in "format=json&data=" this format

Comment: you must send the same data structure starting from "format=json&data="  as mentioned here https://imgur.com/zvdNil9

Answer (score 0):

I am doing like this, but not worked for me, geting "format=json&data=" error

```
    $client = new Client();

    $data['shipments'][] = [
        'add'=> 'f425 bsquare mohali',
        'phone'=> '9888429895',
        'payment_mode'=> 'Prepaid',
        'name'=> 'Lalit Mohan',
        'pin'=> '145001',
        'order'=> 'RH5E171FCFDEEBA',
        'seller_gst_tin'=> '06AAMCA5258P1Z1',
        'gst_cess_amount'=> '100',
        'client'=> 'Lalit Mohan',
        'tax_value'=> '100',
        'city'=> 'Mohali',
        'weight'=> '100',
        'product_quantity'=> '2',
        'state'=> 'Punjab',
        'waybill'=> '4468910000173',
        'order_date'=> '20170520',
        'total_amount'=> '21840',
    ];
    $data['shipments'] = json_encode($data['shipments']);
    $data['pickup_location'] = [
        'name'=> 'Randh Panchkula',
        'city'=> 'Panchkula',
        'pin'=> '160101',
        'country'=> 'India',
        'phone'=> '9888429895',
        'add'=> 'randh panchkula Address'
    ];
    $data['pickup_location'] = json_encode($data['pickup_location']);

    $client = new Client();


    $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://staging-express.delhivery.com/api/cmu/create.json', [
            'headers' => [
                'authorization' => 'Token XXXXX',
                'contentType'=> 'application/json'
            ],
            'form_params' => [
                'format' => json_encode($data),
            ],
        ]);
    $response_data = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
    dd($response_data);
```